# MySQL Error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key - when I use BIGINT for key types

Tags: mysql, database

I was trying to forward engineer an EER data model using MySQL Workbench 6.3. I received the following error:

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint
SQL Code:
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `proub`.`login` (
      `login_id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
      `login_username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
      `login_password` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
      `login_status` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT '',
      `last_update` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT '',
      PRIMARY KEY (`login_id`)  COMMENT '')
    ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 6 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

This was the first table in the script. When I changed the first table script to another, error occurs in it too. In short, no table gets created. Note that I selected DROP OBJECT BEFORE EACH CREATE OBJECT, also key constraints were consistent.

WHAT I DID:

I reverted all my key types from BIGINT to INT and problem was solved. Please can someone enlighten me about this issue, and maybe best thing to do? I don't understand why It could be happening this way. MySQL VERSION IS 5.6. Thanks!

Comment: It the SQL-command trying to add foreign key constraint that refers to the table, that is being created, itself? That probably doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @J.J.Hakala I just change the table's script position and there was no change. However, I don't encounter any issues when I change all key types from BIGINT to INT

Comment: It's likely you actually missed some of the INT columns that referred to login_id (or other fields). MySQL requires referring column in a foreign key to have the same type and size as the column it refers to.

Comment: @weirdan.  If there is no issue with using BIGINT, then as weirdan commented, I might have mixed types for some key and its foreign. But what is astonishing is that what ever table script put first, the problem occurs in it - In short no table is created when I use BIGINT for all my keys.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

WHAT I DID:

I reverted all my key types from BIGINT to INT and problem was solved.